# Unable to import view in Django project

Tags: python, django, pycharm, pythonpath

I am starting a very basic Django project (using PyCharm IDE in the process). This is what I do initially.

1. `cd` into my `workspace` directory and run `django-admin.py startproject mysite`. This creates the following directory structure:

[image]

2. Run `cd mysite`, followed by `python manage.py runserver`. This works as expected, and I am able to view the standard localhost served page in my browser.
3. Now I need to add another directory called `customviews` inside `mysite`, and inside that add a file called `myview.py` with a basic method that returns a `HTTPResponse` object. Now the folder structure is this:

[image]

4. Now I want to map `URL` to this view, so I head off to the `urls.py` module, and try to import the method in the view I just created. It shows as unimportable. So I add the path to the PyCharm IDE specified Python path here and mark `mysite` as src folder:

[image]
[image]

5. Now the PyCharm errors are gone, and I am able to import like this: `from myview import current_datetime`. However, the command line, where I started the server in the 2nd step throws error, and consequently the mapping fails and so does the page I want to load

[image]

Please help me fix this error!

P.S I have previously worked with Django on Eclipse, I never faced this kind of issue. This is my `urls.py` code:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import *
from myview import current_datetime

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add that directory to the path.

You have two issues: firstly, as adriansq points out, you need an empty `__init__.py` in that directory. And secondly, it is in the wrong place; it should be one level higher, directly under the outer `mysite` directory.

Comment: This is what the default configuration looks like, what `django-admin.py` generates. Why should it be changed? It works fine for the default welcome page..

Comment: Hmm, problem solved. Although I still had to mark the `customviews` directory (now placed directly under the outer `mysite` directory) as source root. May be it is a PyCharm thing. And in addition to my `myview.py`, I added an empty `__init__.py` within `customviews` as well, then imported my file like `from customviews.myview import current_datetime`. Can you explain the logic behind this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please us the code of the file where you want to import the view? 
I think you have missed to create a `__init__.py` inside the customviews folder?